# Which is the best model organism to implement an evolutionary study for P.falciparum?

Tags: phylogenetics, protein-evolution, malaria

I have to study and implement some evolutionary statistics for P.falciparum. In your opinion and by your experience, which organism should I consider in order to take the orthologs to implement this study?In general, If I wanted to extend this study to P.knowlesi, P.vivax and in general to all the parasites evolutionary related to the asian monkey plasmodia, which organism you suggest me to consider as a template? I thought about P.berghei but, since I have to consider also the Vinckeia parasites (mouse plasmodia) is there a good organism, out of the plasmodium genus, that could come in handy serving as a reference point for all these species?

Obliged

Comment: Is there a reason to not do all of them, if you are only doing computational analysis ("evolutionary statistics")? The meaningfulness of the work will increase significantly with each additional organism included.

Comment: Yes the analysis is set to take in consideration the whole set of the organisms. I have only to find a good protozoan to take the orthologs. In human M. musculus is good enough, but for plasmodia?I though about some haemosporidia. What can you suggest  me?

Comment: i would suggest taking orthologs from as many species as possible (ideally 10+ minimum) and using their phylogeny to combine information. estimates will only get better with more information.

Comment: Thank you for your precious suggestion